# WSO2 ESB Deployment Synchronizer stuck (can't gracefully shutdown or deploy services)

Tags: deployment, synchronization, wso2-esb

We are facing some issues with WSO2 ESB sincronizer, since we have a clustered configuration, we are using svn to store the content of "repository/deployment/server". The carbon.xml configuration is the following:

```
<DeploymentSynchronizer>
    <Enabled>true</Enabled>
    <AutoCommit>false</AutoCommit><!--true for the mgt node-->
    <AutoCheckout>true</AutoCheckout>
    <RepositoryType>svn</RepositoryType>
    <SvnUrl>https://svn/x/trunk/serverESB/desenv/</SvnUrl>
    <SvnUser>user</SvnUser>
    <SvnPassword>password</SvnPassword>
    <SvnUrlAppendTenantId>false</SvnUrlAppendTenantId>
</DeploymentSynchronizer>
```

It works correctly for some time, but after some deploys and undeploys it stops working. Although it still gives the message that it is going to sincronize and the svn update seems to be corectly performed, the esb does not load the newly deployed XMLs:

```
TID: [0] [ESB] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.SynchronizeRepositoryRequest} -  Received [SynchronizeRepositoryRequest{tenantId=-1234, tenantDomain='carbon.super', messageId=f9b51e23-8a3c-4f08-acb0-5a1f0f4590b2}]  {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.SynchronizeRepositoryRequest}
TID: [0] [ESB] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.SynchronizeRepositoryRequest} -  Going to synchronse artefacts.  {org.wso2.carbon.core.deployment.SynchronizeRepositoryRequest}
```

Normally after this message it prints INFO saying that new services where deployed, but it does no occour.

When i try to shutdown the server it gives me the message "Waiting for deployment completion...", and gets stuck (so i have to kill using "kill -9"):

```
TID: [0] [ESB] INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement} -  Waiting for deployment completion... {org.wso2.carbon.core.ServerManagement}
```

If I manually restarts it, all the deployments will work fine, and the sincronizer will start to work fine again (for some time).

p.s: I've tryed to use the OS's svn (SuSe) and also the SVNKit module. Our svn repository version is 1.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few docs out there which are not upto date; hence would make things more difficult. Even I have tried those and ended up with unexpected problems.

Have you tried the instructions provided in latest WSO2-product clustering docs?

http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Cluster/Creating+a+Cluster
http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Cluster/Configuring+Deployment+Synchronizer

These information are upto date, and well tested with a sample set-up (ESB cluster with one Manager node and three worker nodes fronted by an Elastic Load Balancer). If you have followed those instructions, this should work fine. If you have already followed the same steps respectively and got stuck with this issue, please do confirm whether you have followed the instructions provided by this document, or not.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, there are a lot of docs outdated. I've tryied these links already, now I'm going step by step with version 4.7.0 and it seens to be working corectly. Hope it still stable, ty